# Page title tag translated based on view title

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I've been working on a multilingual site using [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) modules, with the 'translate view' ('Internationalization Views') module, provided by i18n, active too.

I can translate the view's title and the content, but what I need to translate now it's the content of the tag `<title>`. I've searched the web, but didn't found any answers to this problem, can anyone help me?

EDIT:

I didn't see that the problem actually apply on just one view.
The text in italian is "cinematismi" and it should be translated into "Wiper mechanisms".

In the "translate interface" section I see the following strings:
(the first one doesn't matter because it was an old view)

[image]

The problem is that all strings are actually translated.
Can someone tell me what string should it be?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, see the answer before (I realized i did not set it as correct)

Comment: It's better check it as accepted to help another users to find the correct answer ;-) good luck in your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Actually managed to do it. I'm still not really sure on what did the work, but I tried to handle the taxonomy translation too using entity translation. The view's name was based on a taxonomy name, so it's probable that translating the name of that taxonomy added the title tag translation some way (I hadn't done anything else, so...)

Comment: By "*... translating the name of that taxonomy ...*" you made that translation available to what "i18n views" was looking for (and before you added that translation, the best alternative/compromise for views was to show the not-translated version).

Answer (score 2):

You need the [Internationalization Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module. After install it you can translate the strings of the view.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you really much for the answer, but I'm already using the internationalization views module, sorry for the misunderstanding, but in my module list it appears as 'views translation' under the 'internationalization' section. I have already translated all the texts in that section, but nothing happened

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be solved with the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. That is capable of rewriting Page titles and supports i18n.
Additionally you might need the Metatag Views sub-module that comes bundled. That way you can override the default page title in Views.